# Multiple stitching

Tags: c#, image

I used the code from [Automatic Image Stitching with Accord.net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/automatic_panoramas.aspx)
i changed the code to stitch multiple images

My code after selecting multiple files was

```
img1 = new Bitmap(imgName[0]);
```

I change the code for **btnBlend**

```
Blend blend = new Blend(homography, img1);  
pictureBox.Image = blend.Apply(img2);  
img1 = new Bitmap(blend.Apply(img2));`
```

I added the part `img1 = new Bitmap(blend.Apply(img2));` so i can keep the first stitch image as my copy and this is were to sticth the other image.

Then at the **btnDoItAll**

```
for (int x = 1; x < NumOfFiles; x++)  
{  
  img2 = new Bitmap(imgName[x]);  
  btnHarris();  
  btnCorrelation();  
  btnRansac();  
  btnBlend();  
}
```

After running it, there's no error at all but when it goes to the looping part at the *btnBlend* c# hangs and displays **vshost.exe has stop working**

any help to correct this?

Comment: Did you step into the `btnBlend()` method to see where _exactly_ the problem is?

Comment: if i didn't put the `img1 = new bitmap(blend.Apply(img2))`. the stitching would not be saved. maybe that's the problem. but what should i replace it?

Comment: _Maybe_ can normally be clarified to _definitely_ or _definitely not_ by setting a breakpoint at the problematic code and stepping through. That's why I said _exactly_ before.

Comment: i've already done it. it really was the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the resulting image of the first stitching is not flat and must be transform to flat image before sewing a new image